# Does anyone know this brand logo?

Tags: kitchens, sink

I'm trying to identify the maker of my kitchen sink. It has a stamp on the bottom, but I've had no luck identifying the company name. I live in a house just south of Minneapolis, Minnesota in the United States. My house was built in 1984 and this sink appears to be original to the house based on the date stamp.

It looks like a "4" and a "J" combination to me, but I can't find any manufacturer that matches that.

Has anyone ever seen this logo before, or does anyone know based on the photo of the sink who made it?

[image: sink maker logo]
[image: full logo context]
[image: sink photo]

Comment: Well, someone may know from the States... However, what are you wanting to do? New taps or drain bits or replace the whole thing?

Comment: I was thinking of replacing the whole thing, but it's a kind of unique-looking style, and heavy-duty enameled cast iron, so before pulling it out completely I wanted to learn a little more about it.

Comment: FWIW, I think it looks good. Should be possible to measure the pipe centers underneath and see about replacement taps. And making a hole in a new worktop is easy.